# python exercise with multiple

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm newbie. I'm trying to find out a solution to an exercise but i'm not so skilled and I made several attempts with no results.

I have to write sort of a game.
To start, the computer has to ask you to decide a number X. If the number is a multiple of 4 the user starts.
Otherwise the computer will.
Taking turn, computer and user subctract a number from 1 to 3 to "X" and get a value Z.
The one who wins the game subtracts the latest balls and lets with no balls to pick the other contestant (in this case the user).
I have to write everything in a fashion that the computer will get the wins, always.
Below, the code I have so far written.
Any hint?

```
x = int(input("how many marbles?"))
if x%4==0:
    print("you start")
    y = int(input("subtract 1 or 2 or 3 marbles: "))
    z=x-y
    print("there are ",z," marbles left")
else:
    print("computer starts")
    if x==x+3:
        m=x-3
        print("there are ",m," marbles left")
    if x==x+2:
        m=x-2
        print("there are ",m," marbles left")
    if x==x+1:
        m=x-1
        print("there are ",m," marbles left")
```

Comment: I've removed the [tag:pygame] tag. The [tag:pygame] tag addresses the [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news) library, but is not intended for a game written in Python.

Comment: *"if the number is a multiple of 4 the user start firstly. Otherwise the palyer will start first"* - what?

Comment: I think by 'player' he meant the computer.

Comment: Your embedded if statements inside your else are wonky. X will NEVER equal X+1 (or 2 or 3).

Comment: @RussJ yes I noticed that as well. I think he meant to take the modulus to get the remainder

Comment: actually i made a mistake. I meant that the player will start first if the number of balls is a multiple of 4. Otherwise, the computer start first and this is just where i found the biggest problem

Comment: I'm not getting any syntax error from your code. Can you [edit] your question to focus on a problem you have? If you get an error - post it. If the behavior is wrong - explain why

Comment: it doesn't give me syntax error, i have problem in executing the part where the computer has to play

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to place the logic into a loop and implement a winning condition (given that you are somewhat cheating in deciding who starts, the computer will always win).

Also, your computer player should be checking for the modulo 4 of the number of remaining balls which you can verify using `x%4 == 1` for example ( `x == x+1` will never be True ).  And, given that the computer will always play the modulo 4, you don't need several conditions, you can just use it directly.

```
x = int(input("quante palline ci sono? "))
player = 'P' if x%4==0 else 'C'         # player starts if multiple of 4
while x > 0:
    if player == 'P':       
        print('tocca a te')                       # human player
        y = int(input("togli 1,2 o 3 palline: ")) # ask for balls
        x -= y                                    # remove them
        player = 'C'                              # switch player
    else:
        m = x%4                         # computer plays x MOD 4
        print("il computer toglia",m)   # tell the human player
        x -= m                          # remove balls
        player = 'P'                    # switch player
    print("sono rimaste",x,"palline")   # report balls remaining
print('il computer vince')              # computer always wins
```

*Sorry if my Italian isn't great, only did 1 year of it 25 years ago*

```
quante palline ci sono? 12
tocca a te
togli 1,2 o 3 palline: 3
sono rimaste 9 palline
il computer toglia 1
sono rimaste 8 palline
tocca a te
togli 1,2 o 3 palline: 3
sono rimaste 5 palline
il computer toglia 1
sono rimaste 4 palline
tocca a te
togli 1,2 o 3 palline: 1
sono rimaste 3 palline
il computer toglia 3
sono rimaste 0 palline
il computer vince
```

Comment: First of all, thank you so much. Probably my explanation was not so good. If the number of balls is multiple of 4, the player should start, otherwise the computer will start first. Now i hope that i made my self clear

Comment: I understood that from the start, your explanation was clear enough.

Comment: @penelope mark the question as answered by clicking on the check mark underneath the vote signs